# MVC3 contextDB to perform DML operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm using mvc3 application. Here I am using the contextdb class of the entity framework to get the data from the database. But can we perform insert, update, delete operations  using contextdb, if so how?

Here is my code:

http://oakdome.com/programming/MVC3_Simple_DBContext_Class.php

Answer (score 0):

yes u can.Try using Scaffolding Templates to perform CRUD Operations.
Select the Scaffold Template accordingly to Create Views and Controller for each Operation

Comment: thanks. but without using the entity data model and templates, i want to perform the insert,update,delete operations.